# How to handle exception on a behaviour subject

Tags: c#, exception, system.reactive, behaviorsubject

I have a behavior subject

```
var source = new BehaviorSubject<int>(0);
```

I then process that source with something like

```
var withErrors = source
            .Select(v =>
            {
                if (v == 2)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Ouch ");
                }
                return v;
            })
```

I want to subscribe to withErrors in such a way that I can skip
the errors. An attempt with catch like this.

```
public IObservabe<int> SkipError(IObservable<T> source){

    return source
       .Catch(e=>SkipErrors(source.Skip(1));
}
```

and then call it thus

```
var withoutErrors = SkipError(withErrors);
```

the Skip is an attempt to avoid repeating the last error on the behaviour subject but alas it doesn't work that way. Skip doesn't skip over errors but only over valid data so the error from the current state in the behavior subject keeps getting through.

Is there a clever way of writing Skip that will also skip over errors. Something tells me this is not possible but hopefully I'm wrong

Comment: Actually I've come to the conclusion that this is impossible to achieve. As according to the RX spec an Observable cannot continue after calling OnError there is nothing you can do to get the next value after the OnError is called. I will need to insert some logic to where before the error is generated.

Comment: Correct. Your question is in direct conflict with the Rx spec. Note here it is not the BehaviorSubject that errors, but the projection (Select operator), not that that is very relevant.

Comment: I've realized that if I wish to propagate errors like this I need IObservable<Exceptional<T>> where Exceptional is defined like https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/6154972 and is essentially a container which can hold either an Exception or a Value

Answer (score 2):

As the premise of the question is wrong I present a `better` way to do this using the `Exceptional<T>` monad. For example

```
IObservable<int> source = ....;
IObservable<Exceptional<string>> withErrors =
    source.Select(i=>Exceptional.Execute(()=>{
        if(v==2){
            throw new Exception("Ouch");
        }
        return v.ToString();
    });


IObservable<Exception> errors = 
    withErrors.Where(v=>v.HasException).select(v=>v.Exception);

IObservable<string> values =
    withErrors.Where(v=>!v.HasException).select(v=>v.Value);
```

and just for fun you can do

```
Exceptional<string> r = 
         from x in Exceptional.Execute(() => "xxx")
         from y in Exceptional.Execute(() => "zzz")
         select x + y;
```

which will generation an Exceptional holding the value "xxxzzz". If any of the steps does throw an exception then it will short circuit and hold only the Exception.

My implementation based off another SO answer is https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/6154972

Comment: yes, one way to tackle the problem is to turn exceptions into data.  Another is to catch and consume exceptions without letting them escape out of your code.  Both schemes let you decide exactly which parts of your code can continue running uncorrupted if an exception occurs.